# Live Chat event for Apple's Keynote Address (WWDC 2019)

Tags: discussion

As most of us know, each year Apple hosts its Worldwide Developers Conference (WWDC). Typically, Apple launches the WWDC with a keynote address during which it introduces upcoming software and hardware.

This year the conference will be held in San Jose, California, from Monday 3 June until Friday 7 June.

To coincide with this, we're holding a live chat event right here using [**Ask Different Chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat). Users are invited to join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) as the announcements unfold.

Below is part of the invite Apple issued for the event:

[image]

**Expected announcements**

- iOS 13
- macOS 10.15
- tvOS 13
- watchOS 6

**Rumoured announcements**

- A new modular Mac Pro

**Surprise announcements**

- Let's find out together! :)

**Time of Keynote address**

The Keynote address is scheduled for 10am on Monday 3 June 2019 (Pacific Time). This equates to:

- **Adelaide** - 2.30am, Tuesday 4 June
- **Amsterdam** - 7.00pm, Monday 3 June
- **Auckland** - 5.00am, Tuesday 4 June
- **Beijing** - 1.00am, Tuesday 4 June
- **Berlin** - 7.00pm, Monday 3 June
- **Hong Kong** - 1.00am, Tuesday 4 June
- **Jerusalem** - 8.00pm, Monday 3 June
- **London** - 6.00pm, Monday 3 June
- **Moscow** - 8.00pm, Monday 3 June
- **New Delhi** - 10.30pm, Monday 3 June
- **New York** - 1.00pm, Monday 3 June
- **Paris** - 7.00pm, Monday 3 June
- **Perth** - 1.00am, Tuesday 4 June
- **Rio de Janeiro** - 2.00pm, Monday 3 June
- **Rome** - 7.00pm, Monday 3 June
- **Singapore** - 1.00am, Tuesday 4 June
- **Sydney** - 3.00am, Tuesday 4 June
- **Tokyo** - 2.00am, Tuesday 4 June

[**You can also check your local timezone here**](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=Ask%20Different%20Live%20Chat%20Event%20-%20Apple%27s%20keynote%20address%20at%20WWDC%202019&iso=20190603T10&p1=283&ah=1).

So, for some of us (me included) it'll be a very late night or a very early morning!

Hope to see you there!

Comment: Anybody in attendance @ WWDC this year? This has been a pending item in my bucket list for well over a decade. I wish to cross it out soon :)

Comment: Can the post be edited to include image from the [media invite](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D7LvB18XoAAacy8.jpg:large) card?

Comment: @NimeshNeema It's on my bucket list as well! :) As for the image, the reason I didn't include the full version was just so the post didn't take up too much space. But I suppose we can resize it so it's not so big, so I'll do that now.

Comment: :). I hand code using `<img>` tag when attaching images to a post to have full control over the size.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Great minds think alike! LOL

Comment: The WWDC 2019 Keynote just concluded. Thanks Monomeeth and @grg for hosting the event and making everyone aware. Thanks Monomeeth for welcoming everyone. I am waiting for the video to release and will share a written summary of the announcements soon!

Answer (score 1):

#### [WWDC by Sundell](https://wwdcbysundell.com)

Daily coverage of Apple’s WWDC 2019 conference, by John Sundell.

This may be an interesting resource for all the Apple developer folks hanging out on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Apart from WWDC keynote which happens on the opening day which announces the new operating systems for macOS, iOS, watchOS and tvOS, a ton of other events and sessions take place throughout the week. Notable are The Developer State of Union and plethora of technical sessions where engineers present and dissect the changes to the APIs and tooling.

WWDC by Sundell aims to cover WWDC for folks who may not be able to attend in person.

> However, not everyone is able to actually attend WWDC in person. Not only do you have to win the “lottery” in order to qualify for purchasing a ticket, you also need to have the monetary means to be able to fly to, stay at, and attend the conference. So for a huge amount of people, WWDC can feel a bit out of reach.
>
> I wanted to do something about that. This website is for everyone who wants to closely follow WWDC, but from anywhere in the world. Starting right now, this site will be updated daily with articles, videos, podcasts, and interviews, covering all things WWDC — from recommendations on what session videos to watch, to in-depth looks at new APIs, to interviews with people from all over the Apple developer community.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. :)